# Why does Cypress not recognise the testid of a react-datepicker element?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, react-datepicker

**Target**

To make Cypress recognise and manipulate a DatePicker element.

**Problem**

I cannot make Cypress recognise the data-testid of a DatePicker element, and so have no way of testing it E2E.

**Error**

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: [data-testid="edit_dob"], but never found it.
```

**Attempts**

I have tried placing the DatePicker element inside input and div elements to target instead, but they fail as expected for other reasons.

I have also looked through the docs for both DatePicker and Cypress for mention of the other, and for similar questions here.

**Code**

The code below works as expected, it's just Cypress that seems to be incompatible with the DatePicker input.

```
  function displayEditDetails() {
    let listOfForms = [];
    for (const detail in details) {
        listOfForms.push(
          <FormGroup controlId={detail} key={`key_edit_${detail}`}>
            <FormLabel>{detail.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + detail.slice(1).replace('_', ' ')}</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              data-testid={`edit_${detail}`}
              type={detail}
              value={details[detail] || ''}
              onChange={handleDetailsChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        )
    }
    listOfForms.push(
      <DatePicker
        data-testid={'edit_dob'}
        selected={dob}
        onChange={setDob}
        maxDate={new Date()}
      />
    );
    return(
      listOfForms
    )
  }
```

**Test**

```
  it('Displays the edit fields', () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="accountButton"]')
      .click();

    cy.get('[data-testid="editUserDetailsButton"]')
      .click();

    cy.get('[data-testid="user_email"]')
      .should('not.be.visible');

    cy.get('[data-testid="edit_full_name"]')
      .should('be.visible');

    cy.get('[data-testid="edit_dob"]')
      .should('be.visible');

    cy.get('[data-testid="edit_email"]')
      .should('be.visible')
      .should('have.value', 'test@editdetails.com');
  })
```

Once I can target it, I plan to test clearing the current input and typing a new date in. Any help targeting the picker and warnings of further potential pitfalls are appreciated.

Edit: Here's the generated HTML of the form.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input data-testid="edit_email" type="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="admin@example.com" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="full_name">Full name</label>
    <input data-testid="edit_full_name" type="full_name" id="full_name" class="form-control" value="Jareth">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="address">Address</label>
    <input data-testid="edit_address" type="address" id="address" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input data-testid="edit_postcode" type="postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div data-testid="edit_dob">
    <div class="react-datepicker-wrapper">
      <div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
        <input type="text" class="" value="04/03/1999">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button data-testid="confirmChangesButton" type="submit" class="LoaderButton  btn btn-primary btn-block">Confirm Changes</button></form>
```

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML that's being targeted please?

Comment: Posting the HTML got me on the right track. I've just found out about the Selector Playground and it's working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is visible when looking at the HTML generated by running the app.

**DatePicker HTML**

```
  <div data-testid="edit_dob">
    <div class="react-datepicker-wrapper">
      <div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
        <input type="text" class="" value="04/03/1999">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The DatePicker is rendered as an input element inside a few divs, and the test id doesn't target the input.

**Solution**

The Selector Playground API for Cypress suggests `cy.get('.react-datepicker__input-container > input')`, the class of the parent div of the input. With this I can target the DatePicker, clear it, and type new input.

**Notes For Next Time**

1. Examine the HTML
2. Read the Docs more thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

Reference the concepts used in the [`cy.pickDateRange`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts#L236-L275) command in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/). It is [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

In the code for the command, you will find it is necessary to examine the HTML produced and traverse it appropriately for your needs.